# LTspice question using LT3625

Tags: supercapacitor

Trying out the LTspice simulator to test a super capacitor charging circuit. With no load, it's showing that it's drawing 5 A. Surely this can't be correct?

[image: LTspice simulation with LTC3625]

Not there yet. Using the stock standard LTspice model for the [LTC3625](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3625f.pdf), with only one modification, changing the .ic V(out) = 4.4 to .ic V(out) = 0.0, to show how long it takes to charge the capacitors and reach the correct output, it only reaches a max. of VOUT = 2.5 V. Why?

[image]

Comment: what if you change your cell to a common voltage source? my first thought was that maybe it's "shunting" down excessive power from the cell.

Comment: Your graph only shows the first 2 ms - try waiting several hundred ms to see if it settles down to some low value.

Comment: Thank you.  yes it does settle down after 4ms with the small caps. But i wanted to see how long it takes with a fixed current source, i.e a small solar panel.

Answer (score 1):

The supercapacitors in that simulation start out very-nearly charged. In fact the charging ends just after 4ms.

If you change the SPICE Directive *.tran 4m* to *.tran 200m* then you will simulate for 200ms and be able to see exactly what is going on.

To start the supercapacitors discharged just change the directive *.ic V(out)=4.4* to *.ic V(out)=0*.

They have given that simulation a very beefy solar panel which is why the charging current is high. You can replace that solar panel model with your own quite easily; there is an excellent example here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/257426/193946

Comment: Thank you..  Yes i concluded the solar panel definition is not correct as i have a much smaller one and need to limit the input current to see how long it takes to fully charge the super capacitors.  Rapidly learning LTspice.

Comment: The PV is defined using the following directive, i can change the voltage by changing the V100 Line "5" twice.  Is there any way to limit the current to 0.2A with this Directive ?  


.subckt PhotoCell B A

C1 A B 1n

V1 N001 B PWL 0 0 1m 5 2m 4 3m 5

D1 N001 A S2

R1 A N001 75

.model S2 D(Ron=.1 Ilimit=5.1 epsilon=.5)

.ends

Comment: My edits dont seem to have the CRLF on the end, looks fine when i type but its all one line when i save it.