# Proper way to model solar panel using CircuitLab

Tags: solar-cell, circuitlab

I'm trying to simulate a very simple (primitive?) circuit to charge a battery from a solar cell.

The solar cell was scavenged from a long string of lights.  With a 50 Ω resistor it produces about 6.6 V in full sunlight and about 66 mA. In its previous life it charged a Li-ion battery (3.6 V, 6600 mAh) but that's cooked along with the original board.

I am now using a NiCd battery (3.6 V, 600 mAh - one tenth the original) and have built the following circuit:

[image: primitive solar charging circuit]

Is this the right way to model a solar cell *in CircuitLab* with the parameters described above? I have a bad feeling about the current flowing in the circuit as it stands, it seems rather high.

The closest question I found was [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/257253/59900), but it seems like overkill for this model.

As an aside, I did build this circuit and the battery charged to 4.1 V in about 30 minutes at which time I disconnected, since there is no real control against overcharging or other evil things.

Comment: you want simpler than that?

Comment: No, not looking for simpler.  I'm wondering if I have correctly specified the solar cell within the options available in CircuitLab.  For instance, by using s simple battery to represent the solar cell I can't tell CircuitLab how much current it generates.

Comment: the "overkill" question has a correct model , your model uses the same number of parts and gives wrong results.